# nginx multiple static routes not working

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

i have this nginx config:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name myserver;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/;
        index  index.html;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        root /var/www/html2/;
        index  index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

and I don't understand why the `/doc/` route not works, it returns 404 Not Found? The `/api/` and `/` routes work fine.

I already searched and found this https://serverfault.com/questions/684523/nginx-multiple-roots

Thanks

Comment: What is the full path of the file you are attempting to access and what is the URL you are using to access it?

Comment: At the moment i just use the ip of server as url and its a simple index.html file for testing

Comment: Do you mean a URL of `http://x.x.x.x/doc/` to access the file at `/var/www/html2/index.html`?

Comment: yes right, the `http://x.x.x.x/`   works and goes to /var/www/html but when it try `http://x.x.x.x/doc/` its 404

Comment: Try: `alias /var/www/html2/` with a trailing `/`. Either both the `location` and `alias` should have a trailing `/` or neither have a trailing `/`.

Comment: Thanks but the same problem, i have changend now the configuration but still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

No i found the right way, in case anyone else have the same problem.

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name myserver;
    root /;

    location / {
        alias /var/www/html/;
    }

    location /doc {
       alias /var/www/html2/;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```